# Progress 4gl format string with constants

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Is there a way to format a string in Progress with a specific character?

An example is showing an SSN with x's for the first 6 numbers.
I've attempted to use the String function, but it does not respect the letter x being sent in with the format.

```
SSNString = '333224444'.
SSNString = String(SSNString, "xxx-xx-9999").
//This displays 333-22-4444 instead of xxx-xx-4444.
```

Comment: I think the term for what you are wanting to do is "masking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way to change this format with String function.

If you want to keep only the last four digits, you can try something like this:

```
SSNString = '333224444'.
SSNString = "xxx-xx-" + SUBSTRING(SSNString, 6, 4).
```

Answer (score 1):

The `STRING` function parameter is intended only to format the output string to a desired pattern, not to replace chars on it "on the fly". You'll need a `CHAR` variable to put the database value on it and you can use the `OVERLAY` or `SUBSTRING` function to override the first five chars on your string to match your criteria. In your example :

```
SSNString = '333224444'.

/* Choose the OVERLAY function or SUBSTRING function. You can pass either
   a FILL function call, one variable or a fixed string value to OVERLAY 
   or SUBSTRING function call. They'll behave exactly the same way. */

OVERLAY(SSNString,1,5,'CHAR') = FILL('X',5).
SUBSTRING(SSNString,1,5) = 'XXXXX'.

/* At this point, SSNString is XXXXX4444 */

SSNString = STRING(SSNString,'XXX-XX-9999').

/* Here you'll have XXX-XX-4444 */

MESSAGE SSNString
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
```

In a little more complex and flexible way you can use a function that returns the value formatted as you desire and dismiss the need to use a variable in cases which you want to apply special format to database field values.

```
FUNCTION formatSSNString RETURNS CHAR
    ( INPUT pSourceString   AS CHAR,
      INPUT pFormat         AS CHAR,
      INPUT pOverlayCount   AS INT,
      INPUT pStart          AS INT,
      INPUT pCharOverlay    AS CHAR ):

    DEF VAR cCharOutput     AS CHAR NO-UNDO.

    cCharOutput = pSourceString.
    OVERLAY(cCharOutput,pStart,pOverlayCount,'CHAR') = FILL(pCharOverlay,pOverlayCount).
    cCharOutput = STRING(cCharOutput,pFormat).

    RETURN cCharOutput.

END FUNCTION.

DEF VAR SSNString       AS CHAR NO-UNDO.

SSNString = '333224444'.

/* This returns XXX-XX-4444 */
MESSAGE formatSSNString(SSNString, 'xxx-xx-9999', 5, 1, 'X') 
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

/* This returns 33X-XX-X444 */
MESSAGE formatSSNString(SSNString, 'xxx-xx-9999', 4, 3, 'X') 
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

/* This returns 333-XX-4444 */
MESSAGE formatSSNString(SSNString, 'xxx-xx-9999', 2, 4, 'X') 
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

/* This returns 333-XX-44YY */
MESSAGE formatSSNString(formatSSNString(SSNString, 'x(9)', 2, 4, 'X'), 'xxx-xx-9999', 2, 8, 'Y') 
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Hope it helps.